# Command to work on all files in a folder and output result to single file

Tags: shell-script, files, text-processing

I have a list of files, 10 to be exact, in a recipe folder. I must determine the number of occurences of each word in all the files and then order them according to these frequencies. I can get my command to work on one file at a time, but I need it to work on each file at once and then output to one single file. For example: The word **salt** appears a total of 25 times overall, then output would be: 25 salt. 
So far I have this:

```
sed -d 's/\s/\n/g' < lyrics01.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr >> lyrics01wordcount.tf
```

I need this to be altered to work on every file in the directory, I understand why it is working on one above. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The `-d` option is not in any `sed` I can find, what does it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -d 's/\s/\n/g' * | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr >> lyrics01wordcount.tf
```

Simple.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. You don't need to use redirection with `sed`. It treats any filenames as input data. So `sed ... lyrics01.txt` works just as well as `sed ... < lyrics01.txt` (better, in fact, because...)
2. Without redirection, you can specify multiple files to `sed`: `sed ... file1 file2 ...`, or, in your case, just `sed ... *.txt`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the background info there, and the cool little quicker way to make it better. Very helpful my friend.